# Django Rest Framework nested serializer returns empty list

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two models which are related by one to many relationship. I want to use the first model called Return to post data and another one called Assessment to retrieve data. My models are as follows:-

```
from django.db import models

class Return(models.Model):

    room_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number_of_rooms = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    price_per_night = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    actual_turnover = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Return'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Returns'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.room_type}'
    
    #  A function that return number of days in a month
    def days_in_month(self):
        
        # Get the year and month from the date field
        year = self.created_at.year
        month = self.created_at.month
        
        # Use calendar.monthrange() to get the number of days in the month
        num_days = monthrange(year, month)[1]
        
        return num_days

    @property
    def potential_turnover(self) -> float:
        return float(self.days_in_month()) * float(self.number_of_rooms) * float(self.price_per_night)
    
    @property
    def total_number_of_rooms(self) -> float:
        total = 0
        for obj in Return.objects.all():
            total += obj.number_of_rooms
        return total
    
    @property
    def total_potential_turnover(self) -> float:
        total = 0
        for obj in Return.objects.all():
            total += obj.potential_turnover
        return total
  
    
    @property
    def gross_amount(self) -> float:
        total = 0
        for obj in Return.objects.all():
            total += obj.actual_turnover
        return total

        
   
class Assessment(models.Model):
    return = models.ForeignKey(Return, related_name = "returns", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Assessment'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Assessments'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.return.room_type}'
    

    @property
    def gross_amount(self) -> float:
        total = 0
        for obj in self.return.all():
            total += obj.actual_turnover
        return total
    
    @property
    def total_levy_charges(self) -> float:
        # ! Adjustment must be computed
        adjustment = 0
        return float(self.gross_amount()) - float(adjustment)
    
    @property
    def bed_night_levy_payable(self) -> float:
        rate_of_bed_night_levy = 0.01
        return rate_of_bed_night_levy * float(self.total_levy_charges)
    
    @property
    def total_monthly_bed_night_levy(self) -> float:
        # ! Penalty must be computed
        penalty = 0
        
        return float(penalty) + float(self.bed_night_levy_payable)
```

And the serializers are below:

```
class ReturnSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Return
        fields = (
            'id',
            'room_type',
            'number_of_rooms',
            'total_number_of_rooms',
            'price_per_night',
            'potential_turnover',
            'actual_turnover',
            'total_potential_turnover',
            'gross_amount'
 

        )
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        returns_data = validated_data.pop('returns')
        asessment = Return.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for return_data in returns_data:
            Assessment.objects.create(assessment=return, **return_data)
        return assessment    

class AssessmentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    return = ReturnSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Assessment
       
        fields = [
            'id',
            'return',
            'created_at',
            'gross_amount',
            'total_levy_charges',
            'bed_night_levy_payable',
            'total_monthly_bed_night_levy'
            
        ]
```

And views are as follows:-

```
class ReturnView(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, GenericAPIView):
   
    serializer_class = ReturnSerializer
        
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Return.objects.all().order_by('id')
        return queryset
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
class AssessmentViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
   
    serializer_class = AssessmentSerializer
    
    queryset = Assessment.objects.all().order_by('id')
```

And urls are as follows:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers

from .views import (
    
    AssessmentViewSet,
    ReturnView,
)

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register('assessments', AssessmentViewSet, basename='assessments')


urlpatterns = [
    path('',include(router.urls)),
    path('returns/', ReturnView.as_view(), name='return')
]
```

I want to use */returns* endpoint to post data, and */assessments* to retrieve data.

When I post the response is as shown below:

```
"results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "room_type": "Single",
            "number_of_rooms": 2,
            "total_number_of_rooms": 2,
            "price_per_night": "10000.00",
            "potential_turnover": 40000.0,
            "actual_turnover": "8000.00",
            "total_potential_turnover": 40000.0,
            "gross_amount":"8000.00",

        },
    ]
```

But in *\assessments* endpoint it returns an empty list and nested serializer does not work.

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
          return:[]
        }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the naming should avoid keyword like `return`, try to rename your model first?

Comment: Worked on your suggestion, but I still don't manage to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        returns_data = validated_data.pop('returns')
        asessment = Return.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for return_data in returns_data:
            Assessment.objects.create(assessment=return, **return_data)
        return assessment
```

`Assessment` model class does not have `assessment` field. Also `assessment=return` **return** is not defined. It should be **`assessment`**. Also `validated_data` won't have 'returns' key because `ReturnSerializer` does not have `returns` key. So `Assessment` objects are not created.